# How to pass an argument to a TypeScript decorator at runtime?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I would like to pass an argument to a TypeScript decorator at runtime so that the decorated method will use that argument, the original method doesn't reqiure this to function but the decorator does.

I tried to achieve that by passing an argument to the decorated method and then find it within the decorator in the original method's arguments.

For example what I tried:

```
// calling a decorated method (nestJS code)
@Get('')
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
async getAll(@CurrentUser() user: User): Promise<any[]> {
//current user is a nestJS decorator extracts the user from the http header
    const res = await this.whateverService.original(user);
    return res;
}


// @MyDecorator usage
@MyDecorator()
async original(@user user: User): Promise<any>{
  // return get all whatever
}


// @MyDecorator decorator
export function MyDecorator() {
    return function (target: Object, propertyName: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {

        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        // get user param index
        const userParamIndex = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(
            userMetadataKey,
            target,
            propertyName
        );

        if (userParamIndex === undefined) {
            throw new Error(`user undefined or missing @user decorator in method ${propertyName.toString()}`);
        }

        // override method descriptor with proxy method
        descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                const user = args[userParamIndex];
                let res;
                try {
                    // await stuff using user arg;
                    res = await originalMethod();
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } finally {
                    // await stuff;
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        };
    };
}


// @user decorator
export function user(
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    parameterIndex: number
): void {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(
        userMetadataKey,
        parameterIndex,
        target,
        propertyKey
    );
}
```

The issue I have with this implementation is that the `user` argument in original is marked as `declared but its value is never read.` in the IDE.

Is there a way to let the IDE know that it is in use in the decorator?
Or maybe a better implementation for that?

### Edit

For some more context, the code I've added is simplified and doesn't includes all functionality.
The purpose of all that is:

1. get a single connection to a postgres db from a connection pool.
2. setting the current_user_id to a session run time variable, for row level security needs.
3. execute the original method that will execute db queries.
4. reset the session run time variables.
5. release the connection
6. return the result of the original method.

Tech stack: NestJS & TypeORM.
I'm trying to mimic something like [TypeORM's Transaction decorator](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/decorator/transaction/Transaction.ts) but with extra functionality.

Comment: You could prefix the name, `_user`, but it seems to me that decorating a method shouldn't require adding additional parameters to that method simply so they can be implicitly passed to the decorated method under the hood. It makes things rather confusing, even if you made omitting it a compile time error instead of the current runtime error that you throw, which you can by the way. An alternative would be to require that the decorated member is defined in a class that has access to the current user.

Comment: Oh, thanks prefix is new to me. I also think it's confusing, maybe Decorator is not the appropriate solution for my issue. The code base I develop is a web server, due to that I wouldn't like to have a state such as the current user in the server's code. I used the Decorator as a solution for code repetition, but this piece of code requires value that changes at runtime.

Comment: It depends on where the user comes from. Can you show an example of calling the decorated method for context?

Comment: I've edited the code example and added some more info at the bottom.